# PHP PDO: Differences between the methods of retrieving a single-column result

Tags: php, pdo

What's the difference between

```
$PDOStatement->fetchColumn();
```

and

```
$PDOStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

(if one exists)? Or are they functionally similar but only aesthetically different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `fetchColumn()` will return only  `'value'` while other by default will return `array('column_name'=>'value')`. You'd have to use `setFetchMode()` to change that.

```
$PDOStatement->fetchColumn($colno);
```

would be equivalent to:

```
$PDOStatement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, $colno);
$PDOStatement->fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the doc [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) for fetch, there doesn't seem to be a PDO::FETCH_COLUMN style.  If that's true, then the difference is fetch will return a row, while fetchColumn will only return the specified column.

Answer (score 0):

By default fetchColumn() will return only 'value' while other by default will return array('column_name'=>'value'). You'd have to use setFetchMode() to change that.

Comment: literally copied from the chosen answer.